# Who coined the phrase "boos come from the cheap seats"?

Tags: etymology

Who was the first to coin the phrase along the lines of

> the loudest boos come from the cheap seats

?

Some searching around the origins of the phrase (and its variations) see it attributed to various individuals including [James Lee Burke](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/743581-the-boos-always-come-from-the-cheap-seats-we-gain), and [Babe Ruth](https://m.facebook.com/crazydavidsdiscountvariety/posts/2247205891981855/), but it's not clear who coined it.

A search for "cheap seats " on [n-gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22cheap+seats%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) offers some clues as to the time period of the phrase's origination:

[image]

Comment: The results of your research should be mentioned in your question and the links to the references this research yields should also be   provided,  so that the reader will be able to see by himself what is being said and explained.

Comment: @LPH done, hope it helps.

Comment: The opposite opinion is that the cheapest seats are filled by those who want to be there most, compared with those who may want to be seen and must always have the best. I once assigned a 10th-row center seat *for dance* to a dignitary, who predictably was pissed off and exchanged it for front row. Those place you under the dancers. A bit back shows you the big shape. And they're not cheap.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in versions with "cheap seats"? Throughout history theatres and arenas have had cheaper and more expensive areas but with different names. I'm sure the sentiment is old, whether true or not.

Comment: Ngram finds [no](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boos%20come%20from%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) examples of '*boos come from the*'; [nor](https://%20https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22from%20the%20cheap%20seats%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) of 'from the cheap seats'. Your second link explain that Ruth meant those people with least invested in the game. If this needs explaining each time the phrase is used, perhaps it isn't deemed useful.

Answer (score 3):

In U.S. newspapers, use of "cheap seats" to convey the meaning "inexpensive seats" goes back to the 1850s at least. The earliest Elephind newspaper database match for the phrase involves a [classified advertisement](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030213/1857-08-08/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22cheap%2Bseats%22) in the *New York Daily Tribune* (August 8, 1857):

> BOOKKEEPING, WRITING, ARITHMETIC.—Mr. DOLBEAR, No. 609 Broadway, will receive a few more STUDENTS on Monday, to prepare practically for Fall business. One $15 Seat for a full Commercial Course may be secured this day or evening. Apply early for **cheap Seats**.

Here "seats" refers simply to a place in the classroom, and "cheap" means "low-priced," suggesting that, as the starting date for the class approaches, the price of a seat will go up.

The phrase "cheap seats" is even more straightforward (and prosaic) in "[Our Boston Correspondence](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=DAC18580818.2.5&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%22cheap+seats%22-------)," in the *[San Francisco, California] Daily Alta California* (August 18, 1858):

> Rev. Dr. Gannett's Society, who worship in Dr. Channing's old church, in Federal street, talk of selling out their house and moving up town. The Pine street church (Rev. Mr. Dexter's, Orthodox,) have sold their building (leasing it for one year for present use), and will erect an immense edifice, with **cheap seats**, at the South-end, foot of Dover street.

Since seating at churches was (and continues to be) free in most congregations, I surmise that "cheap seats" here refers to the quality and cost of the furniture—not to the price of admission to occupy one.

In the 1860s, we begin to see instances of "cheap seats" specifically in reference to inexpensive places to observe an event or performance. From "[The Execution of Muller](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026403/1864-12-17/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22cheap%2Bseats%22)," in the *Sunbury [Pennsylvania] American* (December 17, 1864), quoting the *[London] Times* of November 15, 1864:

> The occupants of "**cheap seats**" and "good accommodation" were particularly numerous. The windows of the several houses in front of the drop were well filled, whilst numbers were sitting on the roofs. Preachers of various religious sects were scattered about, and worked with commendable zeal in the distribution of tracts.

And from "[London Amusements](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025925/1867-08-28/ed-1/seq-6/#words=%22cheap%2Bseats%22)," in the *[Philadelphia, Pennsylvania] Evening Telegraph* (August 28, 1867), reprinted from *The Galaxy* for August:

> Those who have had sufficient curiosity to read the fashionable novel which Walter Scott drove from its pedestal, and which Dickens has buried in oblivion, must have remarked that the opera is there always spoken of with a kind of awe, second only to that, which is excited by the name of Almack's. The nabob who came from India with a bran new fortune, the country cousin who aspired to fashionable life, the young lady who had just come out, are represented as looking forward with a trembling heart to their first night at the opera. For in those days the opera was scarcely open to the public; admission could only be procured by vouchers; the entertainment was monopolized by subscribers and their personal friends. There were no **cheap seats**; the gallery was reserved for servants. If an "outsider," to use a vulgar but expressive word, ventured within those sacred precincts, he felt as if he had entered a private house without an invitation.

As this excerpt makes clear, the original "cheap seats" at performance halls were the ones farthest from the stage—in the gallery, the balcony, or the back of the room.

To this point we have been looking at examples of "cheap seats," but the addition of the definite article "the" to the phrase indicates use of the term in a more categorical way: "the cheap seats" are the place where a less affluent and less refined class of ticket buyers congregates. Consequntly there is a certain degree of interchangeability in the nature of the portion of the audience that occupies those seats, regardless of the particular venue a writer happens to be talking about. Early instances of "the cheap seats" begin to appear in Elephind results from the 1880s. From "[Copperfield Court](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn93067705/1883-06-30/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22the%2Bcheap%2Bseats%22)" in the *[Winnsboro, South Carolina] News and Herald* (June 30, 1883):

> Together they walked in the Park of sunny Sundays, or went to **the cheap seats** of places of amusement, where they had much ado to hear or see anything, and they had nice indigestible little suppers at ten or eleven o'clock.

From "[Jenny Lind's Sympathy](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86069161/1888-04-11/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22the%2Bcheap%2Bseats%22)," in the *[Richmond, Kentucky] Climax* (April 11, 1888):

> "Just consider, Miss Lind!" said one of them [music hall managers], seeing that she remained unaffected. "Crowds of people, who never will have a chance of hearing you again bought up all **the cheap seats**; think of the disappointment to them."

And from "[In the Bull Ring](https://virginiachronicle.com/cgi-bin/virginia?a=d&d=SH18890531.1.4&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22the+cheap+seats%22-------)," in the *[Woodstock, Virginia] Shenandoah Herald* (May 31, 1889), reprinted from *Blackwood's Magazine*:

> How noisy, and hot and dusty they [members of "the motley crowd of sun-burned Spaniards"] all looked as they trooped in and took their seats around me! was surprised at the crowd; there was no great matador going to kill bulls today, yet all **the cheap seats** were filling.

Finally, instances in which a reporter focuses on the rowdy behavior of the mass of people in "the cheap seats" begin to appear in the a890s. From "[Sundry Smiles](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84026844/1894-05-10/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22the%2Bcheap%2Bseats%22)," in the *Wheeling [West Vurginia] Daily Intelligencer* (May 10, 1894):

> "Why, Mr. Gehones, I did not suppose you cared anything for baseball," said the deacon. "I am surprised to see you here." "I didn't come out to see the game," answered the sensational evangelist. "I get a good many expressions for my sermons from hearing those fellows on **the cheap seats** talk to the umpire."—*Indianapolis Journal*.

And from "[The National League](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn95079490/1897-05-28/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22the%2Bcheap%2Bseats%22)" in the *Roanoke [Virginia] Times* (May 28, 1897):

> Pittsburg. May 27.—There was a disgraceful scene after the game. A gang of roughs surrounded Hurst [the umpire in a baseball game between Pittsburgh and Brooklyn, which Brooklyn won] and attempted to mob him as he left the grounds. Whatever Hurst is, he certainly is no coward. He paid no attention to the crowd until one fellow hit him;  then he returned the blow with interest. He doubtless would have been roughly handled, but to the credit of one "Reddy" Mason, the Pittsburg players and several policemen, Hurst was rescued from the mob. Too much praise cannot be given to Manager Donovan, either for his action in quieting the mob previously. The crowd on **the cheap seats** in the left field were making a great howl about a decision of the umpire and were acting in a threatening and insulting manner. Donovan ran across the field and warned the crowd that the first man who made a disturbance would be severely dealt with. He instructed the police to arrest the first offender. His action had immediate effect.

Evidently, booing, howling, threatening, hurling choice epithets, etc., have been recurring features of audience behavior in "the cheap seats" for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

The use of "the cheap seats" as synecdoche for "the common people/the working class, etc" dates back to 1915 at least. It is a reference to the cheap seats in music halls that were populated by the poor. Unfortunately, that example given by Google books is not particularly clear:

"The Saturday Review of Politics, Literature, Science and Artbooks." 1915 · ‎PAGE 107

> The man in the footsteps of Rachmaninoff, instead of in the footsteps of Mozart, ... judges by what he sees and hears ... from the cheap seats of the music halls.

The next mention is

Time - Volume 7 - Page 19 Briton Hadden, ‎Henry Robinson Luce · 1926 PAGE 19

> Together they have fashioned a homely fable of those who watch the song and sorrow of metropolitan life from the cheap seats . Clerks and poor boarding-house folk are their characters.

The nature of what comes from the "cheap seats" obviously changes with the context, so I would not bother too much about the "booing".

PS Your Ngram search would be better without the quotes and as *from the cheap seats*.